# textarea auto insert below code into itself

Tags: html, textarea, jspx

I have some problem with div and textarea tags in jspx. when I call `< textarea >` I need to use to like that: `< textarea > - < /textarea >` . if I don't use hyphen textarea will auto insert all the code below it into itself. 
I example:
`< textarea >< /textarea >`
`< input type="button" />`

so textarea will display text: `< input type="button" />`

p/s: I using " " after < to show you example. I don't use it in my code.
this is my code:

```
                            <td><textarea name='sourceText' class='textarea textarea-long' maxlength='4096'>___</textarea></td>
                            <td><textarea name='targetText' class='textarea textarea-long' maxlength='4096'>___</textarea></td>
```

this is the picture if have hyphen.

http://i.upanh.com/rieluw

and this is the picture if I remove hyphen

http://i.upanh.com/rielec

Comment: do not understand you question

Comment: show a complete sample code

Comment: I have added code and showed example picture.